# Permutation Array

Tags: polynomial-time

Hello I have a problem and would like a help to prove if it is P or not.

> Given an array $\mathcal{A}$ of integers. Is there a permutation of the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ such that, $\forall i \in \{1, ..., |\mathcal{A}|-1\} : \mathcal{A}[i] \neq \mathcal{A}[i + 1]$?

Could anyone give me some direction on how to show if it's Polynomial or not?

Comment: Please do not delete your question after you have received a useful reply. We want questions and answers available in order to not only help you, but also others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for simplicity that the number $n=2k$ of elements in the array is even.
Let $a$ be the (one of the) most frequent element(s) and let $m$ the number of occurrences of $a$ in $\mathcal{A}$.

A polynomial time algorithm that solves your problem is the following: return "yes" if $m \le k$, otherwise return "no".

To see this notice that if $m>k$ the answer is trivially now, since two occurrences $a$ must necessarily be adjacent in any permutation of $\mathcal{A}$.

If $m=k$ then the answer is trivially yes: just interleave the copies of $a$ with the other elements in $\mathcal{A}$.

If $m < k$, then consider the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ in nonincreasing order of their number of occurrences. Create the permutation $B$ of $\mathcal{A}$ by first filling in all odd indices and then all even indices (indices start from $1$).
For each distinct element $x \in \mathcal{A}$, let $i$ be the index of the first occurrence of $x$ in $B$.
If $i=1$ or $i$ is even, then no pair of elements equal to $x$ can possibly be adjacent in $B$.
Suppose then that $i$ is odd and that $i>1$. In order for $B[i-1]$ to be equal to $x$, at least $k$ copies of $x$ would be needed, but at most $m \le k-1$ copies are available.